# updating a boolean value. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, boolean

I'm working on an application where the user fills in a couple textboxes and other buttons change colors depending on what they have filled in. It works pretty decent so far, but I now run into a problem.

There are 10 buttons, when the correct values have been filled in by the user the pressed button changes to red or green. When I press button 6 for example and I fill in everything, it turns green. Then when I go to the next button, button 8, and I fill in everything so the button should become red, it turns green instead. This is because I give 3 boolean variables a value of true at button 6, that turns it green. then when I want to change the value of those booleans for other buttons, they keep the value that was given to them the first time.

This is part of my code,it's just the same code but for the different buttons.

```
If Integer.TryParse(tbAantalIslands.Text, iAantalIslands) AndAlso
            iBtnClickCheck = 6 Then
            If iAantalIslands <= 2 Then
                bQuantityCheck = True
            End If
        End If

        If Integer.TryParse(tbAantalIslands.Text, iAantalIslands) AndAlso
            iBtnClickCheck = 8 Then
            If iAantalIslands <= 2 Then
                bQuantityCheck = True
            End If
        End If
```

This is the code for buttons 6 and 8. It changes the boolean bQuantityCheck to true when iAantalIslands is less than or equal to 2.

here is what i do with that boolean in order to change the color of the button that was pressed.

```
If bQuantityCheck = True AndAlso bMassCheck = True AndAlso bWeightAllParticles = True AndAlso iBtnClickCheck = 6 Then
        btn6.BackColor = Color.Green
        Exit Function


    ElseIf bQuantityCheck = False AndAlso bMassCheck = False AndAlso bWeightAllParticles = False AndAlso iBtnClickCheck = 6 Then
        btn6.BackColor = Color.Red
        Exit Function

    ElseIf iBtnClickCheck = 6 Then
        btn3.BackColor = Color.Red
        Exit Function

    End If

    If bQuantityCheck = True AndAlso bMassCheck = True AndAlso bWeightAllParticles = True AndAlso iBtnClickCheck = 8 Then
        btn8.BackColor = Color.Green
        Exit Function


    ElseIf bQuantityCheck = False AndAlso bMassCheck = False AndAlso bWeightAllParticles = False AndAlso iBtnClickCheck = 8 Then
        btn8.BackColor = Color.Red
        Exit Function

    ElseIf iBtnClickCheck = 8 Then
        btn3.BackColor = Color.Red
        Exit Function

    End If
```

Ss shown here, it will change the color of the button if the set parameters are met.

I have 10 buttons, those buttons stand for thickness of glass, so 6mm, 8mm, 10mm, etc. The application is a tester to see if the glass breaks in the correct way. 3 fields have to be filled in by the user, the amount of islands(loose glass shards of a certain size), the biggest island and the mass of all islands combined. those fields have a range in which they should be in, for example there cannot be more than 2 islands or the glass is not right, the biggest island cannot have a mass greater than 1000mm2.

if the values given by the user are within the correct boundaries, the button that the user pressed to state the thickness of the glass, will turn green. If it's outside those set boundaries it will turn red.

Now if the user has tested the 6mm thick glass and its all good, so the button is green, and user then continues testing with the 8mm thick glass. the 8mm glass has 5 islands for example, so the button should turn red. What happens instead is the values given at the 6mm button don't change, so the boolean that you can see in my code doesn't update to accommodate for button 8. button 8 then turns green when it should be red.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you made and the formatting but your description is confusing. Please provide a clear explanation of the rules and/or the steps required to get the desired output. Code is an implementation of logic so it is important that that logic is clear.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I edited the post with a better explaination, hope its understandable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do here.

You either need to reset your boolean to false before doing the check on button 8, or just use a different set of boolean altogether.

Also keep in mind that AndAlso is [short-circuiting](https://sodocumentation.net/vb-net/topic/2509/short-circuiting-operators--andalso---orelse-), so if bQuantityCheck is true or false, your code is not going to evaluate the other booleans (bMassCheck and bWeightAllParticles).